# Possibility of meeting people with the name Vasco da Gama in Portugal?

Tags: factoids, portugal, local-knowledge

Is it still possible to meet people with the famous name *Vasco da Gama* In Portugal?

Comment: How is this related to travel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about name frequencies, and not about travel.

Answer (score 7):

A Facebook people search for the name 'Vasco da Gama' in Portugal returns multiple results. Some seem handles (not real names), but several appear to be real names of individuals currently living in Portugal.

So, the answer to your question appears to be 'yes'.

(Note, I'm purposefully not linking to the search results. You can repeat the search yourself.)

Comment: You can avoid posting links by taking a snapshot of the relevant info and redacting as needed.  It's not important for this question, but may be helpful for others...

Answer (score 6):

You can still find people with famous names. From your question I assume you know navigators particularly well.

Technically speaking, yes, you can find people named "Vasco da Gama". Both names are still in use. How common is it? I would say not that common.

- I checked the list for the last years name preferences and "Vasco" comes around number 30. Unfortunately, I can't check before 2010.
- "Gama" is a family name, and this one does not even appear in the [100 most common surnames](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_dos_cem_apelidos_mais_frequentes_em_Portugal). The last one of the list shows up with a percentage ocurrence of 0.26%. Presumably, "Gama" will be even less.

So, as you can see, the probability of finding both names together is even lower... but not impossible, as "MastaBaba" mentioned.

Other names like [Fernão de Magalhães](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Magellan) (known internationally as Magellan - which gave the name to the GPS company) are not even currently used. Although the surname *Magalhães* is still in use (with a 0.50% ocurrence), *Fernão* is not. The variant *Fernando* is used instead. If you consider *Fernando* to be acceptable than you will find them for sure (depending on how much you look for).

Many other famous portuguese names from the 15-17th century evolved to some variant or might be residual depending.